# How to create a SQLAlchemy database in one python file and use it in another python file of same project?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask_sqlalchemy to create a database in file1.py as:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime


db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


class DataBase(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    path = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, default='Incomplete')

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I want to use this database in another python file which already hass `app = Flask(__name__)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the second file has an `app`, you will need to import the db engine from the current file
First of all, try not to use numbers in file names (and generally give better names)
So I recommend you call `file1.py` something like `dal.py` (dal for data access layer), and `file2.py` something like `main.py` or `app.py`.
This is how your folder should look like:

```
src -
    | app.py
    | dal.py
    | __init__.py
```

Afterward, you have a few options

1. import the app from `app.py`
   in `dal.py` you can do the following. This is not the best practice, but it will work

```py
from app import app
...
def init_app():
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

2. init the app in `app.py`, I think this is the better idea.
   In `app.py`, do the following

```py
from flask import Flask
from dal import db

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init(app)
```

I highly recommend reading [the docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) and how to handle imports in python, I this [this](https://realpython.com/python-import/) is a nice article

Comment: ok, got it. How can I make an object (instance) of the class in dal.py inside app.py to use it ?

Comment: The same way with the app, you import and use it, see the docs, and search for some examples online, [this](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sqlalchemy/) is a nice tutorial for the package

Comment: can you type the code pls, I am a little confused

Comment: [here you go](https://pastebin.com/iZ7z6QDw), I highly recommend reading a beginner's guide. Using imports is an essential tool in python (and coding in general)

Comment: so I did this and its showing an error that the object don't have the table (which is present in the class) what should I do now?

Comment: Did you create the table in the DB?

Comment: yes, you can confirm it yourself. the code I shared has a well defined table structure. pls help

Comment: I am sorry, but I think it will be best if you will follow a tutorial like the one I linked